# Proxying OpenVPN UDP over Nginx?

Tags: nginx, openvpn, udp

I'm using Nginx stream module to reverse proxy OpenVPN over UDP. Reverse proxying another protocol such as DNS works, but when I try to reverse proxy UDP I get messages from OpenVPN:

```
Sun Sep  4 14:45:32 2016 us=371479 MULTI: multi_create_instance called
Sun Sep  4 14:45:32 2016 us=371587 127.0.0.1:54025 Re-using SSL/TLS context
Sun Sep  4 14:45:32 2016 us=371618 127.0.0.1:54025 LZO compression initialized
Sun Sep  4 14:45:32 2016 us=371692 127.0.0.1:54025 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1542 D:1212 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Sun Sep  4 14:45:32 2016 us=371723 127.0.0.1:54025 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1542 D:1450 EF:42 EB:143 ET:0 EL:3 AF:3/1 ]
Sun Sep  4 14:45:32 2016 us=371764 127.0.0.1:54025 Local Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1542,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,cipher BF-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-server'
Sun Sep  4 14:45:32 2016 us=371790 127.0.0.1:54025 Expected Remote Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1542,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,cipher BF-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-client'
Sun Sep  4 14:45:32 2016 us=371823 127.0.0.1:54025 Local Options hash (VER=V4): '530fdded'
Sun Sep  4 14:45:32 2016 us=371855 127.0.0.1:54025 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '41690919'
RSun Sep  4 14:45:32 2016 us=371915 127.0.0.1:54025 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:54025, sid=a7c6a891 9390f563
WWWW
```

and the client never finishes connecting. How can I make this proxy correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Basically Free Nginx Edition support for UDP proxying is limited to DNS requests, and it never assumes UDP session might be longer than a couple of milliseconds

You should stick to TCP for proxying OpenVPN or install [NGINX Plus commercial version](https://www.nginx.com/products/session-persistence/), which actually supports [state file for UDP connections](https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_upstream_module.html#state) allowing them to be persistent (as one of features unavailable otherwise).

P.S. Another option would be to wait a few months, until they include full functional into Open Source version. [Judging by their feature release frames](https://dzone.com/articles/announcing-udp-load-balancing-in-nginx-and-nginx-p), it should be available for free in early 2017...